# mouseover sometimes fires instead of touchstart - why?

Tags: javascript, events, touch

I have found a very strange behavior that I cannot explain. Want to do the following:

A handler needs to react to a `touchstart` **or** `mouseover` event, depending on the type of input device. Note that I want to support hybrid devices (with both mouse and touchscreen) and I cannot rely on pointer events.

Now, I just setup both `touchstart` and `mouseover`events. And for the most part it works just fine. Also use `preventDefault` to prohibit simulated "mouse" events firing after touch events. But what is totally confusing to me is that *sometimes* there is a still a `mouseover` event occuring, and if I remove the preventDefault, it even seems that the `mouseover`is firing **instead** of a `touchstart`. Why oh why is this happening?

Furthermore, this is reproducible with both Android and iOS! Though it seems to be more easily triggered with Android (using Chrome).

I have prepared a little testcase so you can try for yourselves. Note that this behavior seems only triggered when you tap somewhere on the border between the red DIV (which has the events) and the background. Just tapping in the center works 100%. And you may need more or less tries until it happens.

Any help greatly appreciated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Touchtest</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background: #222;
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      font-size: .9em;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    #test {
      position: fixed;
      top: 100px;
      right: 100px;
      bottom: 100px;
      left: 100px;
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function testEvent(event) {
      console.log("testEvent", event);
      if (event.type === "mouseover") {
        alert("MOUSEOVER DETECTED");
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    var ele = document.getElementById("test");
    ele.addEventListener("touchstart", testEvent);
    ele.addEventListener("mouseover", testEvent);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you will look at the mousedown event coordinates you will find that when you click on the edges (just outside) in the mobile mode using Chrome the coordinates are not correct.

Comment: Hey there I can't reproduce your bug in chrome, https://jsfiddle.net/xvtgc36r/1/

Comment: Hmm, your code differs a bit. Also make sure you test on a touch device.

Comment: @Rewanth, yeah might also be part of the apparent bug we see here. There is something going wrong for sure.

Comment: @frontend_dev I have a solution but its not absolute. Try to add border to the div tag, change the border color to the background color, add padding. By doing so you will be compressing your div tag and its border gets mixed up in the background color, so if the user clicks slightly outside the radius then also only the touchstart event is fired instead of mouseover. Make sure that size of border equals to the maximum radius of touch(this is the bug). You can make advanced changes to this idea to overcome this bug in your application. But I still encourage you to report this bug to chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've poked around your example a bit and it seems like a bug in Chrome. I couldn't reproduce it in Firefox.
You can reproduce it in Chrome developer tools on desktop and in fact I've found a way to reproduce it in a 100% of cases:

- open dev tools and switch to device mode
- place the circle cursor on the edge of red rectangle so that the center of the cursor is outside of the red rectangle
  [image: chrome dev tool cursor]
  sorry for the image quality, I can't capture this cursor with a screenshot
- click
- for it to work the next time, you have to first click on the black background away from red rectangle

So it seems like this happens when the center of the touch is outside of the rectangle, but the radius of the touch overlaps the rectangle.
That said, I'm not sure what you can do here except file a bug report

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I observed. At first, I also thought of a bug. But wait ... try in iOS again, and the behavior is exactly the SAME. So this is why I am so confused. Could this be a very old bug, referring back to the days when Chrome and Safari shared the same code (aka Webkit)?

Comment: I'm not sure how much code Webkit and Blink share nowadays, but one being a fork of the other, they very well might have the same logic for triggering touch events. But anyway, this behavior doesn't seem like something implemented on purpose to me, it seems like either an overlooked side-effect of emulating mouse event while using touch devices or an actual bug. Either way you should probably report this issue to Chrome and iOS browser teams, they might give you a much clearer answer :-)

Comment: I guess you are right. Thanks for checking this and I think you deserved your bounty ;)

Answer (score 2):

Mouse events (mouseover, mouseout, mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, etc) are specific to the mouse input device.

The mouseover javascript event would translate to the touchenter touch events. This events is part of a W3C draft (currently, just Firefox support), so if you want to use it, you must implement your onmouseover feature using touchmove event and looking at the coordinates and to see if they overlap with the coordinates of your html element.

I think that it helps you.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but you did not read my question carefully, and in addition your answer is just wrong. So first of all, mouse events are NOT specific to the mouse input device! Mouse events are generated _as well_ when using touch, as so called "synthetic events". When using touch, BOTH touch and mouse events are generated, with mouse events usually firing after the touch events. My question actually is about the client firing a "mouseover" event ONLY when using touch (i.e. _without_ preceding touch events) under certain circumstances (which should not happen and makes things a lot harder).